# Android 2.1 device to remote mysql database connection

Tags: mysql, database-connection, android-2.1-eclair

I am developing an app that should connect to some server machine and access to a database on it. I have followed various tutorials online and now I am confused. Can someone please tell me what is the way of achieving this? webviews php server client? too many things I have seen in my mind and now confusing me.

I need a clean idea.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do in my opinion:

Write (in PHP, ASP.NET, JavaEE, whatever server side web programming language you want) a little HTTP Restful API to access your remote database.

You will issue HTTP REQUEST to GET/MODIFY data in MySQL and you will receive JSON responses. JSON will be very easy to parse and integrate with your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no JDBC driver for android / MySQL. So you can't connect to your database as a desktop application or a web server would.

Use [webservices](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/W/Web_services.html) in php using `SOAP`  , `XML-RPC` , or  `REST`.

It will be easy.

The term Web services describes a standardized way of integrating Web-based applications using the XML, SOAP, WSDL and UDDI open standards over an Internet protocol backbone. XML is used to tag the data, SOAP is used to transfer the data, WSDL is used for describing the services available and UDDI is used for listing what services are available.